# NHibernate ICriteria with a bag

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Just a quick question. If I've got 2 tables that are joined in a 3rd table with a many-to-many relationship, is it possible to write an ICriteria with expressions in one of the tables and the join table?

Lets say the mapping file looks something like:

```
    <bag name ="Bag" table="JoinTable" cascade ="none">
      <key column="Data_ID"/>
      <many-to-many class="Data2" column="Data2_ID"/>
    </bag>
```

Is it then possible to write an ICriteria like the following?

```
        ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Data));
        crit.Add(Expression.Eq("Name", name));
        crit.Add(Expression.Between("Date", startDate, endDate));
        crit.Add(Expression.Eq("Bag", data2IDNumber));
```

When I try this, it tells me I the expected type is IList, whereas the actual type is Bag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this (i think)

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Data));
crit.Add (Expression.Eq ("Name", name));
crit.Add (Expression.Between ("Date", startDate, endDate));
crit.CreateAlias ("Bag", "b");
crit.Add (Expression.Eq ("b.Id", data2IDNumber));
```